# TSP - does it have its place in GIS.SE?

Tags: discussion

I am spending some time with Travelling Salesperson Problem and would like other people to share their experience with me. Is GIS.SE good place to ask about TSP algorithms and their comparison or should I move it to StackOverflow or other SE site?

There were some questions about it already like [methods for solving this simple routing problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/methods-for-solving-this-simple-routing-problem) and of course PGRouting related questions.

I don't use other SE sites as often and would like to see what GIS community has to say about the problem, but on the other hand, I feel that it is not the most rightful place for TPS algorithm question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has a place. I recommend balancing the technical stuff with real world concepts.  I suspect gis.SE members typically know a lot more about [ROI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return) than [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Compared to other apps, the ROI for fleet management is very quantifiable.

Comment: Routing is an integral part of GIS. It definitely belongs here.